# Using tkinter move my txt around to any locaiton

Tags: tkinter, text, move

Typical use of insert from tkinter is:

```
text1.insert(5.5,'*')
```

I want to use:

```
for x in 10:
    text1.insert(5.x,'*')
```

but I get invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index is just a string in the formation of *line.character*, so you can use string formatting:

```
for x in range(10):
    text1.insert(f"5.{x}", "*")
```